# Get indexes of selected columns (DataTables + ColVis)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using the jQuery plugin DataTables + ColVis to show tables.
I have to get an array of the *indexes of the columns which the user has chosen to display* (this information will be used for creating a customizable table for export).

For example: A user chooses to display only Browser and Platform(s) from the table [here](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/ColVis/index.html). I need to obtain [1,2].

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT TO PREVIOUS ANSWER

I figured out a better way using datatables API:

```
    //You have to pass the datatable object. 
//in the case of your example you should pass $('#example').dataTable();
    var fnGetVisibleColumns = function(oTable) {
    var counter = 0;
    aColumns = new Array();
    $.each(oTable.fnSettings().aoColumns, function(c){
        if(oTable.fnSettings().aoColumns[c].bVisible == true){
            aColumns.push(counter)
         }
        counter++;
    });
    return aColumns;
    }

//Now you can do var aVisibleColumns = fnfnGetVisibleColumns($('#example').dataTable());
//aVisibleColumns is [1,2] if the user displays only "browser" and "platform" columns
```