# How to get the column index of particular value of td in HTML tables

Tags: html

Hi there,

I created an HTML table and what I need is to find the column index of a particular value,
but I don't know how to access each value of a table. That is why I am unable to get the index of the column.

Here is my table.

```
<table>
     <tr>
         <td>01</td>
         <td>02</td>
         <td>03</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>04</td>
         <td>05</td>
         <td>06</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>07</td>
         <td>08</td>
         <td>09</td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

and I want the index of the value 03.

Comment: you want column index for each td??

Comment: Have you tried anything

Comment: Its already here.Go through it..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062492/get-indexes-of-selected-columns-datatables-colvis

Comment: i need index of 1st row and 3rd column...........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a working code, first traverse the table to get the values in this, then compare with your required value and find the index of it..,

```
 <html>

 <head>
 <script>
function cellvalues() {
    var table = document.getElementById('mytable');
    for (var r = 0, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
        for (var c = 0, m = table.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++) {
            var hi=table.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML;
 if(hi==03)
 {
 alert(table.rows[r].cells[c].cellIndex);
 }
        }
    }
}


   </script>
   </head>
   <body>

   <table id="mytable">
   <tr><td>01</td><td>02</td><td>03</td>
  </tr>
   <tr><td>04</td><td>05</td><td>06</td>
    </tr>
   <tr><td>07</td><td>08</td><td>09</td>
  </tr>
   </table>
 <input type="button" onclick=cellvalues()>
 </body>

  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (untested)

```
var tab = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
var tr = tab.childNodes;

for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    var td = tr[i].childNodes;
    for (var j = 0; j < tr.length; j++) {
        if (td[j].innerHTML == "03") {
            alert(i + "," + j);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using [**jQuery index**](http://api.jquery.com/index/) for this:

```
var trCollection = $('table tr');
$('table td').each(function () {
    console.log(trCollection.index($(this).parent()));
});
```

Comment: Thaks body for that help.